# Qt can't kill process

Tags: qt, process

In my Qt app i run a process under a push-button click.The process run gnome-terminal.My problem is when i kill qt process that run but push-button click from another button by pid,its shows error."kill: sending signal to 19771 failed: No such process" but still terminal running.And if i kill my app,but still terminal running.

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess(this);
if (p)
{
    p->setEnvironment( QProcess::systemEnvironment() );
    p->setProcessChannelMode( QProcess::MergedChannels );
    QString program = "gnome-terminal";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-x" << "bash" << "--rcfile" << "./auto.sh";
    p->start(program, arguments);
    pid= p->pid();
}
```

Button2 cod is:

```
QProcess::startDetached("kill -9 "+QString(pid));
```

how can kill process and also terminal by click another push-button?

Comment: Did you try to call `p->terminate()`?

Comment: You are actually spawning a lot of processes. There is the gnome-terminal, the bash and eventually you also spawn something in auto.sh. You can get information about the current state using ```QProcess::state()```. Instead of using linux-kill command, why not use ```p->kill()```?

Comment: The `if (p)` test is redundant. If `new` fails, it won't return. You won't ever see a NULL `p`.